# How to restrict data sizes in wcf

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

How can I restrict the size of data in wcf?

assume that I have a string which should be less than 256, how can I enforce it? for example I have:

```
[DataContract]
class  DataExample
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
}
```

How can I inform and enforce the client that the Name should be less than 256 char?

Answer (score 0):

Through the datamember / datacontract tags, to my knowledge, you can't. There are a few things you can do on the data contract, like require an attribute to be present etc but they're quite limited.

Comment: Any other option? Not using DataContract or DataMember.

Comment: custom code in your setter to return a faultexception - but nothing thats 'built in'.